# How to add a custom class attribute into code wrapper?

Tags: posts, functions, customization, themes, filters

By default, after publishing codes, the post shows a html like this,

```
<pre class="wp-block-code">
    <code>
        some codes here
    </code>
</pre>
```

I have plenty posts with codes and don't want to edit them one by one. How do I add a custom class attribute globally for all posts? to make it look like this

```
<pre class="wp-block-code custom-class">
    <code>
        some codes here
    </code>
</pre>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On the right of the editor, there should be an "Advanced" tab. Open that and there'll be an "Additional CSS Class(es)" field.

Comment: Okay. Any other solution so that it works globally for all posts without editing one by one?

Comment: After deploying the code, I got an error saying, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting variable(T_VARIABLE)

Comment: The code in that answer is JavaScript, not PHP.

Comment: oops, where should I use that code

Comment: You can see how the JS file needs to be enqueued in the question at that link.

Comment: Thanks bro, it helped anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add your custom class to the old posts at once, you can do this via "[the_content](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/)" filter and using [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) or [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function to do a REGEX replacement.

A working Example:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ){

    // Don't do anything if we're not in a single post
    if(! is_singular()){
        return $content;
    }

    $customClass = 'custom-class';

    return preg_replace_callback(
        '/<pre([^>]+)class="([^"]+)"/i',
        function( $matches )use( $customClass ){
            return '<pre' . $matches[1] . 'class="' . trim($matches[2]) . ' ' . $customClass . '"';
        },
        $content
    );

} );
```